# Type parameter name?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript; I've read the documentation and I have understand the generic type T; but what's the problem in this very simple example?

```
function test1<string>(x:number):boolean{
    let s:string="hello";
    if (x==1 && s==="hello") return true
    else return false
}
```

Compiler says: "Type parameter name cannot be 'string'".
The error is on `<string>`.
For my exercise, I'm trying to define a non generic type parameter, in this example, a `<string>`

Comment: what would be the point of a generic type parameter that could only be string? Wouldn't that be equivalent to not having any type parameter? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What is a non-generic type parameter? Doesn't "type parameter" already suggest "generic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved keywords such as String cannot be used as generic name. To define a non-generic the `extends` keyword can be used. Checkout the following example:

```
interface Lengthwise {
    length: number;
}

function loggingIdentity<T extends Lengthwise>(arg: T): T {
    console.log(arg.length);  // Now we know it has a .length property, so no more error
    return arg;
}
```

More info about generics can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html